# Moving a PHP app to IIS server

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2008

We had a PHP app running on a linux server and just copied the PHP app to a local Windows server.
`phpinfo()` works normal but while viewing the pages we get codes on the page like `''){?>`
or

```
'' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 " ; $sql_result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die ...
```

The index page first line has this code,

```
<? $pagex="mainpage"; include("_inc_header.php");?>
```

Then I change it to `<?php ...` page displays nothing. And when I do not change it Chrome renders it as a comment like `<!-- ....`

When I try the app on my Mac (with MAMP) with small problems it manages to work. Also enabling display_errors I got hundreds of

> Notice: Undefined index:
>   Notice: Undefined variable:
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant

almost making page unreadable :(

As far as I can see there is something with my local Windows server's IIS...
Any idea how to fix it? At least on Mac I do not see PHP codes rendered as HTML :D

p.s.: I have tried include function with a basic PHP on Windows Server and it worked.

Comment: Since you are using `<?` open tags, do you have `short_open_tags` enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was too strange but after enabling short_open_tags and asp_tag=on code worked normally.
Only having some problems with images but when I checked the code, coder did not use a relative path.

Thanks for pointing the short_open_tag guys! :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 <? to <?php
```

in all of your files

or just allow

```
short_open_tags = on
```

in php.ini

Comment: After enabling short_open_tags now all I see is 30 lines of PHP Notice and nothing else:(

Comment: open debugging by adding :

ini_set("display_errors","on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
at the beginning of your code, and debug your code, now PHP is working fine, see what plugins/extensions are missing or if it's a connection issue, just debug the code,

Comment: Adding those line did not change anything, I still have only notices. When I disable short_open_tags site is loaded with some html-like rendered php again

Comment: debug your code, I can't see your code so I can't help, but what I can assure you now is php is working, may be your DB connection is incorrect or something, adding those lines will show you any fatal or parse errors so it can help you debugging your code, but if you're 100% sure that there are no errors after the notices or warnings, (Also view source of the page to make sure), then there's an error in the logic of the code.